# Blood Pressure: Significance of difference between systolic and diastolic

Tags: blood-pressure

I wanted to understand what is the difference between systolic and diastolic readings of blood pressure. I understand 120-80 to about 100-60 is considered normal but does the difference in the two values in the reading hold any significance?

I have read some text [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_blood_pressure) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diastolic_blood_pressure).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference between systolic (the upper number) and diastolic (the lower number) pressures is known as the [pulse pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_pressure):

> Systemic pulse pressure = P<sub>systolic</sub> - P<sub>diastolic</sub>

For a typical blood pressure reading of 120/80 mmHg the pulse pressure is therefore 40 mmHg.

It is proportional to [stroke volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_volume), the amount of blood pumped from the heart in one beat, and inversely proportional to the compliance or flexibility of the blood vessels, mainly the [aorta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aorta).

A low (also called narrow) pulse pressure means that not much blood is being expelled from the heart, and can be caused by a number of factors, including severe blood loss due to trauma, [congestive heart failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congestive_Heart_Failure), shock, a narrowing of the [valve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aortic_valve) leading from the heart to the aorta ([stenosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aortic_valve_stenosis)), and fluid accumulating around the heart ([tamponade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_tamponade)).

High (or wide) pulse pressures occur during exercise, as stroke volume increases and the [overall resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_peripheral_resistance) to blood flow decreases. It can also occur for many reasons, such as [hardening of the arteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/arteriosclerosis) (which can have numerous causes), various deficiencies in the aorta (mainly) or other arteries, including [leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aortic_regurgitation), [fistulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arteriovenous_fistula), and a usually-congenital condition known as [AVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arteriovenous_malformation), pain/anxiety, fever, anemia, pregnancy, and more. Certain medications for high blood pressure can widen pulse pressure, while others narrow it. A chronic increase in pulse pressure is a risk factor for heart disease, and can lead to the type of arrhythmia called [atrial fibrillation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrial_fibrillation) or A-Fib.